# How to submit only the selected values from the drop down list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have the below code and calling the serialize() method on the form:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select id="CouponType" name="CouponType">
        <option value="MONEYOFF">MONEYOFF</option>
        <option value="BONUSPOINTS">BONUSPOINTS</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="SUBMIT ME" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($('form').serialize());
        });

    </script>
</form>
```

What should happen is that only if the drop down list has value then the value has to be sumitted but it always submits the first option in the list so the result of the alert is always the below in IE 7.0, IE 8.0, IE 9.0 and Chrome:

```
CouponType=MONEYOFF
```

How to submit only the selected values from the drop down list?

Comment: http://www.onerutter.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-tips-how-to-get-value-of-selected-option-in-select-box.html

Comment: Because the first option is selected by default, that is how a select works.

Comment: I want a select which allows a no selected option. Do I have to add a new option there with text Please Select and value empty. I liked to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If there's only two options, maybe a `radio` element would be better?

Comment: That you have to add an option above it with a "select XXX" type of text and do not give it a value. That is how select elements work.

Comment: thanks, the problem is I'm using JQuery UI Multiselect which shows check boxes, so there is a situation where no check boxes are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<form>
    <select id="CouponType" name="CouponType">
        <option value="MONEYOFF">MONEYOFF</option>
        <option value="BONUSPOINTS">BONUSPOINTS</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="SUBMIT ME" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($('#CouponType').val());
        });

    </script>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24Hz9/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a blank option that would be selected by default, which would submit no value unless a user chooses one

```
<form>
    <select id="CouponType" name="CouponType">
        <option value="">Select a type</option>
        <option value="MONEYOFF">MONEYOFF</option>
        <option value="BONUSPOINTS">BONUSPOINTS</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="SUBMIT ME" />
</form>

$("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#CouponType').val()) {
        alert($('form').serialize());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ginovva320/C8N7X/

Answer (score 0):

When none is selected, IE 9.0+ makes the SelectedIndex = -1 by default whereas IE 7, 8 and Chrome, make the SelectedIndex = 0 so posts the first item.